# Analogue of eq() filter in Prototype.js

Tags: jquery, filter, prototypejs

I have to assign the different sizes to the `td`, and the width depends on the position of the tag in table.

In Jquery I can write

```
$$('td .yui-dt-liner div[id^=yui-gen]').eq(2).invoke("setStyle",{'width':'122px'});
```

changing the argument in eq.
is there analogue expression in prototype.js ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do here is:

```
$$('td .yui-dt-liner div[id^=yui-gen]')[2].setStyle({'width':'122px'});
```

`$$` returns a plain old array of elements with which you can just access whatever element(s) you need. `setStyle` is an Element method, so you don't have to 'wrap it' or anything like you need to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `$$("td:nth-child(2)")` - this will select 2nd cells in all rows